# Error parsing simpliest query with node-mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

My query method

```js
 connection.query('SELECT * FROM `car_mark`', (err, rows, field) => {
  if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);
  res.json(rows);
 });
```

returns following error:

```
"{"code":"ER_PARSE_ERROR","errno":1064,"sqlState":"42000","index":0}"
```

**Versions as follow:**

> node --version v7.9.0
>
> mysqld  Ver 5.5.55-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64
>
> mysql --version mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.55, for debian-linux-gnu
>   (x86_64) using readline 6.3
>
> "node-mysql": "^0.4.2"

Anyone have an idea, why?

**UPD**
My connection params:

```
'mysql_conf': {
    'host': 'localhost',
    'user': 'root',
    'password': '***************',
    'database': 'cars'
}
```

Comment: That SQL state hints invalid syntax or that the user doing the query cannot access that table.

Comment: But same query in emma returns valid results...

Comment: Are you executing the queries with the same user?

Comment: console.error returns
{ Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

Comment: other queries, like
 connection.query('SELECT * FROM cars.car_model WHERE id_car_mark = ?', [req.params.id], (err, rows, field) => {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  res.json(rows);
 });
returns needed data

Comment: yes user is same

Comment: Try to log the query to understand what is happening `console.log(connection.query('SELECT * FROM \`car_mark\`', (err, rows, field) => {
  if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);
  res.json(rows);
 }).sql);`

Comment: hmmm... console.log doesn't return anything o_O

Comment: In your successful query, you queried `cars.car_model`. In your failing query, you query just `car_mark` with no database specified. What are your connection or pool parameters?

Comment: I try both of this cars.car_mark and just car_mark

Comment: It seems like nodejs caching query because if i comment strings
if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);
and returning
res.send('OK');
i still getting this error

Comment: @m0sk1t Node doesn't cache queries. There's something else in your code that's causing this.

Comment: hmmm... now it works perfeclty (o_O) some king of magic... I just swap this lines
router.get('/marks', getCarMarks);
router.get('/models', getCarModels);
and it works...